# How to join two files in a version control system

Tags: version-control, refactoring, perforce

I am doing a refactoring of my C++ project containing many source files.
The current refactoring step includes joining two files (say, `x.cpp` and `y.cpp`) into a bigger one (say, `xy.cpp`) with some code being thrown out, and some more code added to it.

I would like to tell my version control system (Perforce, in my case) that the resulting file is based on two previous files, so in future, when i look at the revision history of `xy.cpp`, i also see all the changes ever done to `x.cpp` and `y.cpp`.

Perforce supports renaming files, so if `y.cpp` didn't exist i would know exactly what to do. Perforce also supports merging, so if i had 2 different versions of `xy.cpp` it could create one version from it. From this, i figure out that joining two different files is possible (not sure about it); however, i searched through some documentation on Perforce and other source control systems and didn't find anything useful.

Is what i am trying to do possible at all?
Does it have a conventional name (searching the documentation on "merging" or "joining" was unsuccessful)?

Comment: +1 until you asked, it never occurred to me how useful something like this might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done in a classic VCS.
Those versioning systems come in two flavors (slide 50+ of [Getting git by Scott Chacon](http://www.slideshare.net/chacon/getting-git)):

- delta-based history: you take one file, and record its delta. In this case, the unit being the file, you cannot associate its history with *another* file.
- DAG-based history: you take one *content* and record its patches. In this case, the file itself can vary (it can be renamed/moved at will), and it can be the result of two other contents (so it is close of what you want)... but still within the history of *one* file (the contents coming from different branches of its DAG).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try integrating with baseless merges (-i on the command line).  If I understand the documentation correctly (and I've never used it myself), this will force the integration of two files.  You would then need to resolve the integration however you choose, resulting in something close to the file you are envisioning.

After doing this, I assume the Perforce history would show the integration from the unrelated file in it's integration history, allowing you to track back to that file when desired.

Comment: Tried to do it; didn't work. It suggested that i should do a 3-way merge with the first (ancient) version of `x.cpp` as a "base version".

Answer (score 1):

The easy part would be this:

```
p4 edit x.cpp y.cpp
p4 move x.cpp xy.cpp
p4 move y.cpp xy.cpp
```

Then the tricky part becomes resolving the move of y.cpp and doing your refactoring.  But this will tell Perforce that the files are combined.